# CSS3 transform scale() does pixelate some elements

Tags: jquery, css, transform, scale

It's a miracle to me why the scale transform does behave in such a strange way. The two elements shown below in the image have exactly the same html behind, but the scale transform does pixelate some elements...
this strange behaviour just appears after a completed drag & drop on the dragged element, and the elements around the dragged element.

[click to see the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEf4Z.png)

css is the following:

```
div.KE_coverflowContainer {
    vertical-align:top;
    height:122px;
    width:90px;
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:10px 5px 5px 0px;
    background:#e4e4e4;
    position:relative;
    cursor:default;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #bababa;
}
div.KE_coverflowContainerHover {
    -moz-transform: scale(2) translate(0px,29px);  
    -o-transform: scale(2) translate(0px,29px);  
    -webkit-transform: scale(2) translate(0px,29px);  
    transform: scale(2) translate(0px,29px);  
    z-index:1000;
    cursor:move;
    margin-top:0px;
    border:1px solid #bababa;
    -moz-box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);    
}
```

the Hover class is added as the element is hovered... Same effect if I use

```
div.KE_coverflowContainer:hover
```

istead of adding the class by JavaScript (since :hover is not working in IE (on other elements but the <a> element), but mouseenter and mouseleave are, i prefer the JS solution).

Does anyone know how to get rid of this problem?

Is there a other way to redraw an an element than following code?

```
$.fn.redrawElement = function(){
    return this.each(function(index, element){
        var n = document.createTextNode(' ');
        $(element).appendChild(n);
        (function(){n.parentNode.removeChild(n)}).defer();
    });
}
```

I ask because i do this on the end of the drag & drop, but the elements stay pixelated.

---

EDIT:

I know the cause of the blur:

If in Webkit an Element is scaled and then ends up over a `<canvas>` tag, it gets blured/pixelated! Dont know exactly why, but will send a bug notice to Webkit Dev Team.

Thanks for helping anyway :-)

Comment: You could add and (after timeout 0) remove a class to force a redraw. Not sure if that solves the problem though.

Comment: $('.KE_coverflowContainer').addClass('aunusedclass');
   setTimeout(function(){$('.KE_coverflowContainer').removeClass('aunusedclass');},0);

does not help either... :-( or do i have to use a class spicified in the CSS-file??

Edit: giving  answer my self: no not even using a class that exists changes something!

Comment: That is a very strange behavior. Does the problem occur on all browsers? I've made a little demo in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qSS6J/2/) and i don't have any of the problems.

Comment: Thanks, didn't thought about this. It's really just a problem in webkit based browsers (safari, chrome)... FF renders fine... cant test on IE, cause i'm on the Mac side ^^

but the problem continues to exist,  trying to clear cache and reset webkit, maybe then it works...

Comment: Hey, you can answer your own Question to help others :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As said in the edit of the question:**

I know the cause of the blur:

If in Webkit an Element is scaled and then ends up over a `<canvas>` tag, it gets blured/pixelated! Dont know exactly why, but will send a bug notice to Webkit Dev Team.

Thanks for helping anyway :-)

Comment: what do you mean by `tag`?

Comment: and have you tried applying `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 10px);`?

Comment: @marczking i meant a `<canvas>` tag. Corrected. It applied to all transformations in that specific Webkit version.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably choose to scale it down and then remove the downscaling, when you want it in full size.. In that way everything should look smooth 'n clean

Comment: The elements have an image included which is max 300px x 300px and then displayed at 30px by 30px, so that is not the problem! The rest is just a div and p container. so scale should not pixelate.